# How to resolve promise and access contents of fetch request

Tags: typescript, fetch, es6-promise

I can't get a Promise to return a string after having called .then on the fetch call.

I'm accessing a public API and retrieving the rates property from the JSON response.

```
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "rates": {
        "CAD": 1.4867
    },
    "date": "2021-03-16"
}
```

I have a private method that calls fetch on this endpoint and returns a Promise type.

```
    private getCadCurrency(): Promise<Currency> {
        return fetch('https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest?symbols=CAD')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(res => {
                    return res as Currency
                });
    }
```

Currency interface

```
interface Currency {
    base: string,
    rates: string,
    date: string
}
```

When I make a call to getCadCurrency() and then chain it with a .then call I seem to still get Promise object instead of the Rate value.

```
let test = this.getCadCurrency().then(x => { return x.rates });
console.log(test);
```

When I inspect test in the Developer Tools I find that it reports a mixed state - probably when it's originally pending and then its final results.

[image]

What do I need to do to return the rates string?

Comment: You cannot return the actual result.  Your function will return BEFORE the value is available.  All you can do here is return the promise and the caller then uses `.then()` or `await` on the promise to get the eventual value.  That is how asynchronous coding works in Typescript/Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `this.getCadCurrency().then(...)` returns a new promise.  You HAVE to use the value inside the `.then()` callback or use `await` instead.  The only way you ever get a value out of a promise is with `.then()` (where you use the value inside the `.then()` callback) or where you use `await` on the promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I call .then(x => { return x.rates}), why is this not "use"ing the value inside the callback? I had given the linked article a read, but was still confused about how to reach my goal.

Comment: Each `.then()` creates a new promise and what `.then(x => { return x.rates}),` does is set the resolved value of the new promise to `x.rates`.  That's a perfectly fine thing to do, but you still have a promise.  Whoever is receiving that promise will have to use `.then()` or `await` on that new promise and then "using the value in the `.then()` handler" means to actually do whatever your final action is with the value (not passing it on to someone else).  You can also call a function from within the `.then()` handler and pass the resolved value as an argument to that function.

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks for the clarification. Passing the resolved value as a function argument was a missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

Use async/await instead of callbacks.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

```
private async getCurrency() {
  ...
}

async otherFunction() {
  let test = await getCurrency();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted, this is quite literally the standard way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I upvoted because this strategy and the MDN docs got me to where I needed to be, but it doesn't answer the original question about why the Promise won't resolve.